# ngMessages is not working with ngRoute and ngMaterial

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route, angularjs-material

I am creating an Angular App,

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute","ngMaterial","ngMessages"]);
```

When i am using 'ngMessages' with 'ngMaterial', it is not working.

Comment: Are you sure that you are including js of ngMessages or ngMaterial ?

Comment: Define "not working" what error is throwing at you?

Comment: Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have loaded them in the references with the correct versions ,

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs//1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/yllShhhuH1wimgSCqrF7?p=preview)**